# What is the best option to execute 200 requests per minute to an external API in a multi-threaded Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

So, there is an external server (game). There is a market there. A lot of products and their combinations. Their total number is 2146.

I want to receive up-to-date pricing information from time to time.

When the application starts, I create 2146 tasks, each of which is responsible for its own type of product. Tasks run in a separate thread with a delay of 2.5 seconds.

```
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void start() {
        log.info("Let's get party started!");
        Set<MarketplaceCollector> collectorSet = marketplaceCollectorProviders.stream()
                .flatMap(provider -> provider.getCollectors().stream())
                .peek(this::subscribeOfferDBSubscriber)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        collectors.addAll(collectorSet);
        runTasks();
    }

    private void subscribeOfferDBSubscriber(MarketplaceCollector marketplaceCollector) {
        marketplaceCollector.subscribe(marketplaceOfferDBSubscriber);
    }

    private void runTasks() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> collectors.forEach(this::runWithDelay));
        thread.setName("tasks-runner");
        thread.start();
    }

    private void runWithDelay(Collector collector) {
        try {
            collector.collect();
            Thread.sleep(2_500);
            counter += 1;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        log.debug(counter);
    }
```

Using RestTemplate, I access the server. If the price has changed, this task will be completed again after 1 minute. If the price remains the same, add one minute to the wait and again make a request. Thus, if the price does not change, the maximum time between requests for one product will be 20 minutes. I assume that my application will execute up to 200 requests per minute, otherwise I will get a "too many requests" error.

```
    @Override
    public void collect() {
        executorService.schedule(new MarketplaceTask(), INIT_DELAY, MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private MarketplaceRequest request() {
        return MarketplaceRequest.builder()
                .country(country)
                .industry(industry)
                .quality(quality)
                .orderBy(ASC)
                .currentPage(1)
                .build();
    }

    private class MarketplaceTask implements Runnable {
        private long MIN_DELAY = 60; // 1 minute
        private long MAX_DELAY = 1200; // 20 minutes

        private Double PREVIOUS_PRICE = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        private long DELAY = 0; // seconds

        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.debug(format("Collecting offer of %s %s in %s after %d m delay", industry, quality, country, DELAY / 60));
            MarketplaceResponse response = marketplaceClient.getOffers(request());
            subscribers.forEach(s -> s.onSubscription(response));
            updatePreviousPriceAndPeriod(response);
            executorService.schedule(this, DELAY, SECONDS);
        }

        private void updatePreviousPriceAndPeriod(MarketplaceResponse response) {
            if (response.isError() || response.getOffers().isEmpty()) {
                increasePeriod();
            } else {
                Double currentPrice = response.getOffers().get(0).getPriceWithTaxes();
                if (isPriceChanged(currentPrice)) {
                    setMinimalDelay();
                    PREVIOUS_PRICE = currentPrice;
                } else {
                    increasePeriod();
                }
            }
        }

        private void increasePeriod() {
            if (DELAY < MAX_DELAY) {
                DELAY += 60;
            }
        }

        private boolean isPriceChanged(Double currentPrice) {
            return !Objects.equals(currentPrice, PREVIOUS_PRICE);
        }

        private void setMinimalDelay() {
            DELAY = MIN_DELAY;
        }
    }
```

```
    public MarketplaceClient(@Value("${app.host}") String host,
                             AuthenticationService authenticationService,
                             RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,
                             CommonHeadersComposer headersComposer) {
        this.host = host;
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
        this.restTemplateList = restTemplateBuilder.build();
        this.headersComposer = headersComposer;
    }

    public MarketplaceResponse getOffers(MarketplaceRequest request) {
        var authentication = authenticationService.getAuthentication();
        var requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestString(request, authentication), headersComposer.getHeaders());
        log.debug(message("PING for", request));
        var responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(host + MARKET_URL, POST, requestEntity, MarketplaceResponse.class);
        log.debug(message("PONG for", request));
        if (responseEntity.getBody().isError()) {
            log.warn("{}: {} {} in {}", responseEntity.getBody().getMessage(), request.getIndustry(), request.getQuality(), request.getCountry());
        }
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }

    private String requestString(MarketplaceRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
        return format("countryId=%s&industryId=%s&quality=%s&orderBy=%s&currentPage=%s&ajaxMarket=1&_token=%s",
            request.getCountry().getId(), request.getIndustry().getId(), request.getQuality().getValue(), 
            request.getOrderBy().getValue(), request.getCurrentPage(), authentication.getToken());
  }
```

But I have a problem after a few minutes of the application. Some tasks cease to care. The request may go to the server and not return. However, other tasks work without problems. Logs how it behaves (for example):

```
2020-04-04 14:11:58.267  INFO 3546 --- [           main] c.g.d.e.harvesting.CollectorManager      : Let's get party started!
2020-04-04 14:11:58.302 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.g.d.e.harvesting.MarketplaceCollector  : Collecting offer of WEAPONS Q5 in GREECE after 0 m delay
2020-04-04 14:11:58.379 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.g.d.e.market.api.MarketplaceClient     : PING for: WEAPONS Q5 in GREECE
2020-04-04 14:11:59.217 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.g.d.e.market.api.MarketplaceClient     : PONG for: WEAPONS Q5 in GREECE
2020-04-04 14:12:00.805 DEBUG 3546 --- [   tasks-runner] c.g.d.e.harvesting.CollectorManager      : 1
2020-04-04 14:12:00.806 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.g.d.e.harvesting.MarketplaceCollector  : Collecting offer of WEAPONS Q4 in PAKISTAN after 0 m delay
2020-04-04 14:12:00.807 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.g.d.e.market.api.MarketplaceClient     : PING for: WEAPONS Q4 in PAKISTAN
2020-04-04 14:12:03.308 DEBUG 3546 --- [   tasks-runner] c.g.d.e.harvesting.CollectorManager      : 2
2020-04-04 14:12:03.309 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-2] c.g.d.e.harvesting.MarketplaceCollector  : Collecting offer of FOOD_RAW Q1 in SAUDI_ARABIA after 0 m delay
2020-04-04 14:12:03.311 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-2] c.g.d.e.market.api.MarketplaceClient     : PING for: FOOD_RAW Q1 in SAUDI_ARABIA
2020-04-04 14:12:05.810 DEBUG 3546 --- [   tasks-runner] c.g.d.e.harvesting.CollectorManager      : 3
2020-04-04 14:12:05.810 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.g.d.e.harvesting.MarketplaceCollector  : Collecting offer of WEAPONS Q5 in COLOMBIA after 0 m delay
2020-04-04 14:12:05.811 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.g.d.e.market.api.MarketplaceClient     : PING for: WEAPONS Q5 in COLOMBIA
2020-04-04 14:12:08.314 DEBUG 3546 --- [   tasks-runner] c.g.d.e.harvesting.CollectorManager      : 4
2020-04-04 14:12:08.315 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-4] c.g.d.e.harvesting.MarketplaceCollector  : Collecting offer of WEAPONS Q1 in CZECH_REPUBLIC after 0 m delay
2020-04-04 14:12:08.316 DEBUG 3546 --- [pool-1-thread-4] c.g.d.e.market.api.MarketplaceClient     : PING for: WEAPONS Q1 in CZECH_REPUBLIC
2020-04-04 14:12:10.818 DEBUG 3546 --- [   tasks-runner] c.g.d.e.harvesting.CollectorManager      : 5
```

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(8);
  }
}
```

I tried to change the connection pool for one host, but I only made it worse. I even created 200 instances of RestTemplate, but over time the access to the server ceased.

I would not want to use Spring Webflux for this purpose.

What should I do to make the app work as expected?

Comment: Are there server-side errors?

Comment: No. As you can see I get "PING" before a request and there isn't "PONG" after it. I didn't get a response

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map- rest template exchange throws an error for various reasons, you aren't catching it, so pong will never be hit when an error happens

Comment: If everybody starts doing that, that server will get DDOS'ed. Did you ask them if this was the best way to do it? If I was running that kind of server and I wanted people to get real-time updates, I would provide an eventstream endpoint of some sort, and not force people to do 200+ calls  per minute.

Comment: @Thomas__ thank you for the idea. But if an error was present, wouldn't I get a RuntimeException?

Comment: @GreyFairer Unfortunately, developers don't provide even API. They don't answer. I had to discover the API and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Thomas__ thank you very much for the idea! I got `ConnectException: Connection refused` for a few requests. Probably this is the cause of losing particular requests without their renew.